# How to set a value to ion-autocomplete

Tags: angularjs, autocomplete, ionic-framework

I am using ion-autocomplete (https://github.com/guylabs/ion-autocomplete) for my mobile application. I need to set the selected value in ion-autocomplete, which is similar to dropdownlist.

For eg: Autocomplete to displays all the countries, need to set the selected country. If the user already selected the country India, when he open again for edit it should show India selected and also to show other values.

```
 <input ion-autocomplete type="text" readonly="readonly" class="ion-autocomplete" 
                placeholder="Enter the country to search" 
                items-method="getCountries(query)" 
                items-clicked-method="loadStates(callback)"
                item-view-value-key="name" 
                item-value-key="id_country"  
                items-method-value-key="items"  
                max-selected-items="1"  
                autocomplete="off" 
                ng-model="registration.id_country"/>

  $scope.countries =[{"id_country":"1","sortname":"AF","name":"Afghanistan"},
                    {"id_country":"2","sortname":"AL","name":"Albania"},
                    {"id_country":"3","sortname":"DZ","name":"Algeria"},
                    {"id_country":"4","sortname":"AS","name":"American Samoa"},
                    {"id_country":"5","sortname":"IN","name":"India"}]; 

    $scope.getCountries = function(query) {

        var returnValue = { items: [],selectedItems:[] };
        $scope.countries.forEach(function(item){

            if (item.name.indexOf(query) > -1 ){
                returnValue.items.push(item);
            }
            else if (item.id_country.indexOf(query) > -1 ){
                returnValue.items.push(item);
            }
        });

      return returnValue;
    }
```

In ng-model registration.id_country, I am passing the country id. I have tried similar to set the value by passing to ng-model but not successful.

Comment: Did you resolved the issue?
If Success, please do share the solution, so others can use it.

Answer (score 3):

To pre-populate the selected items in the ion autocomplete widget, you have to set the attribute ExternalModel to the initial value you want, and you have to implement a special method model-to-item-method that takes the selected value as an input and retrieves the whole object from your data array. Below is a working code sample. More info [here](https://github.com/guylabs/ion-autocomplete#external-model)

Controller code

```
app.controller('ExampleCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.countries =[{"id_country":"1","sortname":"AF","name":"Afghanistan"},
                    {"id_country":"2","sortname":"AL","name":"Albania"},
                    {"id_country":"3","sortname":"DZ","name":"Algeria"},
                    {"id_country":"4","sortname":"AS","name":"American Samoa"},
                    {"id_country":"5","sortname":"IN","name":"India"}];


    $scope.initialCountry = ["2"];

    $scope.getCountries = function(query, isInitializing) {
        var returnValue = { items: [],selectedItems:[] };
        $scope.countries.forEach(function(item){
            if (item.name.indexOf(query) > -1 ){
                returnValue.items.push(item);
            }
            else if (item.id_country.indexOf(query) > -1 ){
                returnValue.items.push(item);
            }
        });

      return returnValue;
    };

    $scope.modelToItemMethod = function (modelValue) {

    for(var i = 0; i < $scope.countries.length; i++){
      if($scope.countries[i].id_country == modelValue){
        return $scope.countries[i];
      }
    }
    return {};
  };
});
```

HTML

```
  <ion-content ng-controller="ExampleCtrl">
    <input ion-autocomplete type="text" readonly="readonly" class="ion-autocomplete"
            placeholder="Enter the country to search"
            items-method="getCountries(query)"
            items-clicked-method="clickedMethod(callback)"
            item-view-value-key="name"
            item-value-key="id_country"
            items-method-value-key="items"
            max-selected-items="1"
            autocomplete="off"
            ng-model="currentCountry"
            external-model="initialCountry"
            model-to-item-method="modelToItemMethod(modelValue)"
            />
          </ion-content>
```

Comment: Thanks bro, but it didn't worked. I also tried by passing as $scope.registration =  {"id_country":"5","sortname":"IN","name":"India"};. it is showing as 'India' in display but when clicked to change, in that autocomplete list 'India' is not showing as selected

Comment: I gave it another look and I got it working, I updated my answer with a full working sample

Comment: Thanks again. I will try this and get back.

Comment: Have you been able to use it with a restful api call that allows autocomplete?  I have a db with close to a 1M products.

Comment: No, solution is not working, Can you update your answer?